# hours and days of business ( form select )

Tags: javascript, forms

Ok.

I want to create a form, that uses the least amount of code possible, for users to display their opening times and days that their store is open.

I know we can use time picker to select from time and to time.

I want to display:

> Monday
>
> Tuesday
>
> Wednesday
>
> Thursday
>
> Friday
>
> Saturday
>
> Sunday

With opening times from and to, and a close checkbox Next to each day

But it seems coding this will use heaps of html, is their a cleaner way of coding it. Also not sure how to code the close checkbox to discount an entry for a day, so that its value isnt submitted.

Code below: for Monday

```
<label>Monday: </label><select name="from"  id="from">
  <option value="06:00">6:00 AM</option> <option value="06:30">6:30 AM</option> <option value="07:00">7:00 AM</option> <option value="07:30">7:30 AM</option> <option value="08:00">8:00 AM</option> <option value="08:30">8:30 AM</option> <option value="09:00"  selected>9:00 AM</option> <option value="09:30">9:30 AM</option> <option value="10:00">10:00 AM</option> <option value="10:30">10:30 AM</option> <option value="11:00">11:00 AM</option> <option value="11:30">11:30 AM</option> <option value="12:00">12:00 PM</option> <option value="12:30">12:30 PM</option> <option value="13:00">1:00 PM</option> <option value="13:30">1:30 PM</option> <option value="14:00">2:00 PM</option> <option value="14:30">2:30 PM</option> <option value="15:00">3:00 PM</option> <option value="15:30">3:30 PM</option> <option value="16:00">4:00 PM</option> <option value="16:30">4:30 PM</option> <option value="17:00">5:00 PM</option> <option value="17:30">5:30 PM</option> <option value="18:00">6:00 PM</option> <option value="18:30">6:30 PM</option> <option value="19:00">7:00 PM</option> <option value="19:30">7:30 PM</option> <option value="20:00">8:00 PM</option> <option value="20:30">8:30 PM</option> <option value="21:00">9:00 PM</option> <option value="21:30">9:30 PM</option> <option value="22:00">10:00 PM</option>
  </select>
  <label>to</label>
  <select name="to"  id="to">
  <option value="06:00">6:00 AM</option> <option value="06:30">6:30 AM</option> <option value="07:00">7:00 AM</option> <option value="07:30">7:30 AM</option> <option value="08:00">8:00 AM</option> <option value="08:30">8:30 AM</option> <option value="09:00">9:00 AM</option> <option value="09:30">9:30 AM</option> <option value="10:00">10:00 AM</option> <option value="10:30">10:30 AM</option> <option value="11:00">11:00 AM</option> <option value="11:30">11:30 AM</option> <option value="12:00">12:00 PM</option> <option value="12:30">12:30 PM</option> <option value="13:00">1:00 PM</option> <option value="13:30">1:30 PM</option> <option value="14:00">2:00 PM</option> <option value="14:30">2:30 PM</option> <option value="15:00">3:00 PM</option> <option value="15:30">3:30 PM</option> <option value="16:00">4:00 PM</option> <option value="16:30">4:30 PM</option> <option value="17:00" selected>5:00 PM</option> <option value="17:30">5:30 PM</option> <option value="18:00">6:00 PM</option> <option value="18:30">6:30 PM</option> <option value="19:00">7:00 PM</option> <option value="19:30">7:30 PM</option> <option value="20:00">8:00 PM</option> <option value="20:30">8:30 PM</option> <option value="21:00">9:00 PM</option> <option value="21:30">9:30 PM</option> <option value="22:00">10:00 PM</option>
  </select>
  <input type="checkbox" name="closed" value="closed">
<font size="-1"><span>Closed</span>
```

fiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/mf2PB/

Comment: What server side language are you using? Why not generating the HTML on the server side?

Comment: If you don't mind using a JS UI library, there are tons of different date/time pickers out there. What about something like [RightJS](http://rightjs.org/)? Check out the [calendar-with-time demo](http://rightjs.org/ui/calendar/demo#date-with-trigger).

Comment: We could use php, but I am no php expert.

Comment: we currently do use a time picker for other elements on the website. But again the code is protracted, I wondered if we could generate the times dynamically, and apend a id to each element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of several things, although it all depends on the usage.  In reality, all of this is in the HTML, so in the end it is a bit of text that most people won't see.

1. Use JavaScript could populate the options for you, but it would then depend on JavaScript support.  In reality, it just makes your initial html smaller, but you add the JavaScipt code and the DOM elements end up being the same.
            http://www.jsfiddle.net/urQc4/
2. Do this in server-side script.
3. Split your options into hour/minute:
           http://www.jsfiddle.net/q4KcM/

As far as disabling when the closed checkbox is selected, you would need to do that in your form handling, or in a preprocessing script, which would be JavaScript again.

Comment: actually, that is a very intuitive way of doing things, looks neat too. Thanks, I will deffo use this code. Many thanks for your time and effort

Comment: Only issue I havem is submitting those values within a form. Will work on this :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a simple text input field where the user can input things like "6:00 AM - 7:00 PM"and some server side code to check if the time range is valid. To make it easier for the user, use a [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) with a range and 48 possible steps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   function sa_cl() {
    document.getElementById("sa_service_open_time").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("sa_service_close_time").disabled = true;
  }
  function sa_op() {
    document.getElementById("sa_service_open_time").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("sa_service_close_time").disabled = false;
  }
  function su_cl() {
    document.getElementById("su_service_open_time").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("su_service_close_time").disabled = true;
  }
  function su_op() {
    document.getElementById("su_service_open_time").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("su_service_close_time").disabled = false;
  }
  function mo_cl() {
    document.getElementById("mo_service_open_time").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("mo_service_close_time").disabled = true;
  }
  function mo_op() {
    document.getElementById("mo_service_open_time").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("mo_service_close_time").disabled = false;
  }
  function tu_cl() {
    document.getElementById("tu_service_open_time").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("tu_service_close_time").disabled = true;
  }
  function tu_op() {
    document.getElementById("tu_service_open_time").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("tu_service_close_time").disabled = false;
  }
  function we_cl() {
    document.getElementById("we_service_open_time").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("we_service_close_time").disabled = true;
  }
  function we_op() {
    document.getElementById("we_service_open_time").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("we_service_close_time").disabled = false;
  }
  function th_cl() {
    document.getElementById("th_service_open_time").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("th_service_close_time").disabled = true;
  }
  function th_op() {
    document.getElementById("th_service_open_time").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("th_service_close_time").disabled = false;
  }
  function fr_cl() {
    document.getElementById("fr_service_open_time").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("fr_service_close_time").disabled = true;
  }
  function fr_op() {
    document.getElementById("fr_service_open_time").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("fr_service_close_time").disabled = false;
  }
```

```html
    <label for="saturday">Saturday</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="saturday" onchange="sa_cl()">Close
    <input type="radio" name="saturday" onchange="sa_op()">Open<br>
    <label for="sa_service_open_time">Opening Time</label>
    <input type="time" id="sa_service_open_time" name="sa_service_open_time">
    <label for="sa_service_close_time">Closing Time  </label>
    <input type="time" id="sa_service_close_time" name="sa_service_close_time">
    <br><br>

    <label for="sunday">Sunday</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="sunday" onchange="su_cl()">Close
    <input type="radio" name="sunday" onchange="su_op()">Open<br>
    <label for="su_service_open_time">Opening Time</label>
    <input type="time" id="su_service_open_time" name="su_service_open_time">
    <label for="su_service_close_time">Closing Time  </label>
    <input type="time" id="su_service_close_time" name="su_service_close_time">

    <br><br><label for="monday">Monday</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="monday" onchange="mo_cl()">Close
    <input type="radio" name="monday" onchange="mo_op()">Open<br>
    <label for="mo_service_open_time">Opening Time</label>
    <input type="time" id="mo_service_open_time" name="mo_service_open_time">
    <label for="mo_service_close_time">Closing Time  </label>
    <input type="time" id="mo_service_close_time" name="mo_service_close_time">

    <br><br><label for="tuesday">Tuesday</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="tuesday" onchange="tu_cl()">Close
    <input type="radio" name="tuesday" onchange="tu_op()">Open<br>
    <label for="tu_service_open_time">Opening Time</label>
    <input type="time" id="tu_service_open_time" name="tu_service_open_time">
    <label for="tu_service_close_time">Closing Time  </label>
    <input type="time" id="tu_service_close_time" name="tu_service_close_time">

    <br><br><label for="wednesday">Wednesday</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="wednesday" onchange="we_cl()">Close
    <input type="radio" name="wednesday" onchange="we_op()">Open<br>
    <label for="we_service_open_time">Opening Time</label>
    <input type="time" id="we_service_open_time" name="we_service_open_time">
    <label for="we_service_close_time">Closing Time  </label>
    <input type="time" id="we_service_close_time" name="we_service_close_time">

    <br><br><label for="thursday">Thursday</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="thursday" onchange="th_cl()">Close
    <input type="radio" name="thursday" onchange="th_op()">Open<br>
    <label for="th_service_open_time">Opening Time</label>
    <input type="time" id="th_service_open_time" name="th_service_open_time">
    <label for="th_service_close_time">Closing Time  </label>
    <input type="time" id="th_service_close_time" name="th_service_close_time">

    <br><br><label for="friday">Friday</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="friday" onchange="fr_cl()">Close
    <input type="radio" name="friday" onchange="fr_op()">Open<br>
    <label for="fr_service_open_time">Opening Time</label>
    <input type="time" id="fr_service_open_time" name="fr_service_open_time">
    <label for="fr_service_close_time">Closing Time  </label>
    <input type="time" id="fr_service_close_time" name="fr_service_close_time">
    <br><br>
```

Comment: too much code, maybe try to solve their problem rather than making it more complex?